# OData CRUD Operations in ASP.NET Web API without race conditions

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata

In the [official guidance](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-crud-operations) for using OData in ASP.NET Web API, the samples that modify the database all appear to contain race conditions. For example, the sample `UpdateEntity` method calls `_context.Products.Any` followed by `_context.SaveChanges`, but the database may have changed between the calls.

This differs from the boilerplate code generated by Visual Studio for a new Web API with Entity Framework controller, which contains catches blocks for `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`. Is there a similar pattern that is a best practice for the OData update methods?

Additionally, calling `Any` followed by `SaveChanges` involves two database round trips. Is there a best practice to make only one?

Comment: Calling Any followed by SaveChanges will not remove the race condition it will just decrease the risk of overwriting data. I think what you need is to use concurrency token. EF will throw when you try to save your entities but data in the database has already changed. Take a look at this msdn article for more details http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738618(v=vs.100).aspx. Things work in a similar way if you are using DbContext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Any call is just ensuring that the entity that you are trying to update actually exists. You could change that action to,

```
protected override Product UpdateEntity(int key, Product update)
{
    try
    {
        _context.Entry(update).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;  
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return update;
    }
    catch(DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }
}
```

If the entry doesn't exist, `SaveChanges()` would throw a `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`.